# I am trying to export json data to mongoDb from cmd but facing error

Tags: mongodb, windows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJZ34.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIsmB.png)
even though mongod is working on my cmd still facing this issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtpDo.png)
Please help out how to solve this problem So I can export my json file

Comment: Please Use text instead of the image in your question.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [MongoDB Database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools)

`mongoimport` is not part of the MongoDB server package.

Comment: bro it is already installed

Comment: Then you must enter the full path or add the folder where it is located to your `PATH` variable